# Why do we have to wait 60 days between each domain transfer?

Tags: domains, transfer, domain-transfer

I understand that ICANN does make the rules requiring this, but I don't understand why we have to? Each time we do transfer the domain, we have to pay to do so. That partially stops fraud. I also do know that it can take from a few hours to a month for the transfer process to be completed on both ends.

**Why do we have to wait 60 days between each domain transfer?**

Also, allow me to quote the [ICANN FAQ](http://www.icann.org/en/resources/registrars/transfers/name-holder-faqs)

> **If I bought a name through one registrar, am I allowed to switch to a different registrar?**
>
> Yes. The Inter-Registrar Transfer Policy, applicable to all ICANN-accredited registrars, provides that registered name holders must be able to transfer their domain name registrations between registrars. You must wait 60 days after the initial registration or any previous transfers to initiate a transfer.

It states that it is a *requirement* without an understanding of the reason why it is.

Comment: I think this was written to stem the tide against domain hi-jacking. There may be controls in place now that make this unnecessary. I cannot tell you without digging further, but I do know that some registrars are extremely careful about transferring domains and put some security measures in that seem very tight. Perhaps this rule is no longer needed. But then again, there may still be some sleazy registrars out there too. Good point! I would also like to see domain tasting banned. So maybe a re-write is in order.

Comment: NEW as of Dec 1, 2016: As part of this authorization request, the Losing Registrant will also be provided with the option to opt out of the domain's 60-day transfer lock... If the 60-day transfer lock was not opted out of by the Losing Registrant, then the Gaining Registrant will be unable to transfer the domain name to another Registrar for a period of 60 days.
(see https://www.webnames.ca/help/domains/content/resources/articles/domains/domain_transfers/change_ownership__registrant_transfer_/change_ownership__registrant_transfer_.htm for details)

Comment: A related question I just posed about one of the *other* 60-day locks: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/114734/49521

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here is a [Guardlex article](http://guardlex.com/blog/what-is-domain-name-hijacking-or-theft/) that claims that it is to prevent domain hijacking:

> Once a hijacking has been discovered, the responses to it tend to vary. The registrar is sometimes able to return the registration to its original state. However, if the domain name was transferred to a different registrar, this can prove to be difficult. This is especially true if the registrar is in a different country. There have been many cases where the original owner of the domain has not been able to regain control over a domain that was hijacked.
>
> The Internet Corporation for Assigned Names and Numbers (ICANN) requires that there must be a waiting period of 60 days between the time that the registration information is changed and when it is transferred to a different registrar. By doing this, the process of hijacking a domain becomes a tougher task. This is because there is a good possibility that the original registrant will notice the problem during the 60-day window and alert the authorities about the issue. A domain that has been transferred is also a lot harder to reclaim. This is another reason that this method reduces the risk of domain hijacking.

If a domain name were hijacked and the hijacker were able to transfer it several times, getting it back would need to involve all the registrars to which it was transferred.  The process should be simpler if there are only at most two registrars that need to cooperate for the solution.

Comment: Understandable, but at the same time, being social engineered is the person's fault and I have yet to hear of an exploit in systems that handle domains. I will go for this answer, my friend.

Comment: This is a flaw in design. I have a new domain and the provider is incapable of giving support to fix a problem, yet I cannot move my domain away from it due to this ridiculous restriction leading me to a domain that I cannot use for 60 days. Thanks ICANN.

Answer (score 2):

My experience is a little different.  When I transfer a (.com) domain to LCN they offer an option to reject the 60 day lock.  The transfer process takes a week and the domain owner is sent an email for confirmation, no response and the domain doesn't move.  LCN do make a small charge but state that it includes the next 12 month renewal. 
I have a related issue. The transfer lock doesn't apply to .co.uk names, neither does the one week wait, the email confirmation of the small fee.  However when I tried to transfer a "bare" .uk name (as opposed to .co.uk) the current registrar refused quoting the ICANN 60 day limit, and when challenged said bare .uk is handled differently to .co.uk
I've been unable so far to get a definitive view as to whether this is true or if the "losing" registrar is choosing to be difficult.  I've got round the issue for the short-term by changing nameservers and will try the transfer again when the 60 period has elapsed.